# Best inheritance strategy for FOS UserBundle?

Tags: authentication, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to use FOS USerBundle but i have different kind of users(Student, Teacher, Director, etc) who can login into my application.
Each of then have differents properties uniques for each one.

As i see i have some options:

Option 1-To have a User entity inheriting FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User (and set in the config.yml as the user_class for FOS UserBundle) with all the properties for the differents kind of user differenciated by ROLE.
    I particularly don't like this option because User entity will have a lot of properties in null every time a user login in the system(just the properties for the logged kind of user will have values, the rest of properties(almost of there) will be unused.

Option 2-To have a User entity inheriting FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User (and set in the config.yml as the user_class for FOS UserBundle), create one entity for each actor in the application(Student, Teacher, Director, etc) with a relation of OneToOne with the User entity.
    In this way every time a user login, i will be able to say: $logguedUser->getStudent() or $logguedUser->getTeacher(), etc, depending the kind of user loggued in.

Option 3-To have a User entity inheriting FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User, create one entity for each actor in the application(Student, Teacher, Director, etc) and each of that entities inherits from User. This is the option i see in theory better, but i can't figurate how to implemet it since i need to say FOS UserBundle in the configuration witch is user_class, and i will hace some of then(Student, Client, Director, etc). When a actor logged in the application, which object i will have logged?

Do anyone have a better option, or a way to implement the third, or maybe support one? 
Tx

Answer (score 0):

The first option is for lazy programmers, the third is not good because you do not have much interest to differentiate access by user type, you also need to over-configuration.

Personally i'm for the 2 because inheritance can't solve all the problems, evolving application does not mean that a student can not be a teacher or there could be other roles(or multiple roles) and then the inheritance becomes a cage, you can do some [OneToOne relations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional) and Doctrine will do the rest.

There are an Option 4 :) [doctrine still allows some solutions about inheritance mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) and single table inheritance could do for you if you want to use the inheritance